# Android spinnable pie chart

Tags: android, animation, charts, pie-chart

I am new to the Android Graphics and I want to implement a spinnable pie chart, where the user should be able to spin/fling the pie, and it should also respond to click event, like shown in this video,

[youtube example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dT2u96__SiQ)

I tried achartengine, but they dont support spinning in pie charts.

Please help.

Comment: The link is broken. Try another one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just finished up the first draft of such a pie chart, check it out here: https://github.com/saulpower/ExpandablePieChart

Comment: wonderful.. exactly what we need.. I am not able to vote ur answer.. But you are the BEST

Comment: IS it possible to add text or small images inside the pieslices, I tried but couldnt do it with your library.. Thanks

Comment: Great library, but it is possible to add text and images inside each slice.
If yes then please explain.
Thanks.